# how to make up arrow using css only?

Tags: css

I am new to css can you guys please help me out for making custom up arrow:
Below is my html div with only one div I want to make arrow using before and after css properties:

```
    <div class="triangle-with-shadow"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do CSS triangles work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-do-css-triangles-work)

Comment: thanks for your quick help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have tried with below CSS code:

```
.triangle-with-shadow {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.triangle-with-shadow:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 75px;
  left: 25px;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
}
.triangle-with-shadow:before {
    width: 100px;
    background: white;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```